# select-string -pattern wildcard for a specific field

Tags: powershell

I'm still pretty new to powershell. Not sure to fix this or even what I am doing wrong.

My ultimate goal is to pull codes of 5 groups of 5 characters, groups of characters are delimited by -, from a long txt file. Example JTI45-534YS-PKQN6-MSE9S-2PFNM. There are multiple of these and I need to pull them all out of a file at once.

I'm trying multiple different variations on

```
Select-String .\reducedCodes.txt  -Pattern "*-*-*-*-*"
```

or

```
Select-String .\reducedCodes.txt  -Pattern "?????-?????-?????-?????-?????"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(Select-String .\reducedCodes.txt -Pattern '\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}').matches.value`

Comment: Awesome! This has reduced the total text drastically.

However, it has limited down to large lines that include other text.

Is there a way to remove all text that doesn't match this pattern?

Comment: _Is there a way to remove all text that doesn't match this pattern?_ What do you mean. You didnt ask anything like that in the question. Are you trying to write changes back to the file? Your results from the code in comments would not have "extra" characters?

Comment: @Paultheawesome13: Ben's solution will work on Whatever you have asked so far. But if you want to delete all the other characters which are not matching and if you wish to write it back to the file then modify the question and pls provide us a sample

Comment: @BenH You should post an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your string that you are looking for looks like an alphanumeric, you could use a regex word, with is denoted by `\w`. And since there are five in a row, you could use `\w{5}` then they are separated by the `-`character. So `Select-String` normally gives you the lines containing the matches, and you just want the matches, you can then get the `Matches` property, where `Value` is the full match. Also note the `Groups` property where if you put the `\w{5}` inside `()` you could get an individual group.

```
 (Select-String .\reducedCodes.txt -Pattern '\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}').Matches.Value
```

Comment: With what you provided I found quite a bit of additional information and a friend explained some powershell things. I definitely need more time with powershell. All together I got the answer I was looking for. You are the best.